# How to format thousand separator for a number in MS Report Builder?

Tags: reportbuilder

In an report, I want to format number with spaces as a thousand separator. In Microsoft Report Builder, I have an Expression, then I went to Placeholder Properties and in Number tab I choose Custom format: `### ### ### ##0;`

[image: Screenshot of Placeholder Properties]

However in the report, only 2 thousand groups are correctly formatted:

[image: Screenshot of report]

What is correct syntax for custom number format?